# Tag rename request: archlinux -> arch-linux

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request, superuser

Super User has the `arch-linux` and the `archlinux` tags, and the later is a synonym for the former. Could the same be done on Stack Overflow?

Comment: needs moar hyphens

Comment: @Cody Gray: `a-r-c-h--l-i-n-u-x` maybe? :D